# Is my flag in limbo now?

Tags: support

Earlier today (yesterday in UTC), I flagged [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80190/help-lol-i-need-to-solve-this) as "in need of moderator intervention", because it seemed spam-ish, and yet didn't look blatantly off-topic. Other users disagreed, and it has since been put on hold as off-topic.

I was in the minority by believing the question to be on-topic, but still problematic. Cool, no problem.

However, my flag was never marked as "accepted" *or* "declined." It is "pending."

Moderator action has been taken on this question, so I'm wondering if it's some sort of bug that the flag appears to have no action taken on it.

**TL;DR:** I flagged a question. Action was taken (not exactly what I expected), but my flag is still "pending."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no specific timeframe for when a flag will be addressed. Sometimes (and indeed ideally) community action by our members suffices to handle a problematic post, so the issue that was flagged is dealt with before the flag itself is.  This is a good thing — it shows the community is healthy and active, is judiciously self-regulating, and is not requiring the site mods to step in.  We prefer to follow the tenet that [the ideal moderator does as little as possible.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) For situations that aren't actually urgent, as here, it's not that uncommon for a flag to sit unaddressed for a while, both to give the community the opportunity to handle things without relying on one of us to swing a hammer, and because some of us actually do occasionally do things other than moderate Puzzling (*shocking, I know!*).

In this case, the post in question was closed in Review, and has started attracting Delete votes. All before any site mod ever took action on the flags.  So - community, job well done :)

Even when such action occurs, the flag does remain "pending" and visible to the moderators, so it's not actually limbo (though it may be moot by the time it's handled). I've now addressed your flag, so it's no longer pending.

(Note that,  while astonishingly rare, it is possible that something really time-sensitive crops up. Feel free to ping a moderator in [Puzzling's main chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair), where we tend to hang out. Please do be respectful of our time and don't abuse this!)

Comment: OK, thanks. Also, sorry if I insinuated that I was upset that the reaction time wasn't faster. _I was not and am not in any way concerned about reaction time_ - I fully recognize that you guys always get there eventually. I had assumed (incorrectly) that a mod had addressed the question, leading me to believe that my flag had been reviewed by a mod without its status changing. Thanks for the response!